# Handling sequences with the same beginning but different ending with LSTM

Tags: lstm, keras

I recently read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50235563/672018) answer on LSTM internals, but some things are still not clear to me.

Say an LSTM (many to many) is supposed to learn 2 sequences

```
[1,2,3] -> [4,5,6]
[1,2,0] -> [0,0,0]
```

It's supposed to predict 3 steps ahead, based on 3 previous steps. However, in order to predict step 3, steps 1 and 2 must be predicted first. The problem is, the steps 1 and 2 have ambiguous results on their own.

In real world many sequences have the same beginning, but different ending.

- How to make LSTM capable of learning such sequences?
- How is LSTM handling such case internally?

**EDIT**

To answer shimao's comment: "steps 1 and 2 have ambiguous results on their own" how so? it is either [4,5] or [0,0]

[image]

Following the image from the linked answer:

Internal step_1 output is the first element in the output sequence and it's also passed to the internal step_2. The ambiguity is that based on the fist value of the sequence (`1`) we don't know which value should be produced (`4` or `0`). If the internal step_1 produces 4, the net will never be able to predict `[1,2,0] -> [0,0,0]`.

That's my reasoning, which is probably wrong. By this question I'd like to correct it.

Comment: "steps 1 and 2 have ambiguous results on their own" how so? it is either [4,5] or [0,0].

Comment: @shimao Please take look at the edited question.

Comment: Well realistically if your past doesn't predict your future no single machine learning algorithm will be able to predict accurately. I.e. If based on data [0,0] the output will be either 0 or 1 you can't magically correctly decide which one it will be.